# How do I print the number of lines from a File that contains a specific word using Python?

Tags: python, file

This prints out the number of all the lines:

```
def links(htmlfile):
    infile = open('twolinks.html', 'r')
    content = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()
    return len(content)
    print("# of lines: " + str(content.count('</a>')))
```

But I only need the number of lines which contain `< / a >` at the end.

Comment: `return len(content)` will leave the function before printing anything.

Answer (score 2):

The loop way:

```
with open('twolinks.html') as f:
    count = 0
    for line in f:
       if line.endswith('</a>'):
           count += 1
```

Using comprehension:

```
with open('twolinks.html') as f:
    sum( 1 for line in f if line.endswith('</a>') )
```

Or even shorter (summing booleans, treating them as 0s and 1s):

```
sum( line.endswith('</a>') for line in f )
```

Comment: still gives me 8 instead of 2 :(

Comment: @SabahAhmed what's your input?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
with open('data') as f:
    print(sum( 1 for line in f if re.search('</a>',line) ))
```

Comment: Why have you used a regex, when you don't really use it as a regex? You could just do `'</a>' in line`.

Comment: @PeterWood to show OP that different approaches are possible. Also to expand on regex is much easier that  with endwith(). May be OP will want to search for something else in the line .....

Answer (score 1):

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('file') if '</a>' in line)
print num_lines
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that my answer is a bit longer in terms of code lines, but why not use a HTML parser since you know that you are parsing HTML? 
for instance:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.count = 0

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == "a":
            self.count += 1 
        print "Encountered an end tag :", tag
        print self.count

# instantiate the parser and fed it some HTML
parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
        '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1><a></a></body></html>')
```

this is modified code from the python pages. This is then easier to modify if you find the need for collecting other tags, or data with tags etc.

Answer (score -1):

Or you could do something like that:

```
count = 0
f = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    if(line[-5:].rstrip('\n')=='</a>'):
        count+=1
```

Worked great for me.

In general, you go through the file each line at a time,
and see it the last characters (without the `\n`) match `</a>`.
see if the `\n` striping gives you any trouble.